# Filter prevents assigning facts

Tags: optaplanner

I use the OptaPlanner for scheduling exams. Everything regarding the planning works great.

**But**:
To partially pin an exam (fix the room or the timeslot but not both) I use a Selection-ChnageMove Filter.
This works if one of the two is assigned.
But if both are uninitialized, the construction phase always only assigns one (the room). The filter is set to accept everything, so it shouldn't have any impact.
When enabling the trace logging, I can see that OptaPlanner suggests moves (`null->TimeGrain`) but in the end, it never selects one of those moves and results in -Xinit/0hard/0soft and therefore the local search phase can't start.

Is there maybe something wrong with my configuration? Or have I missed a specific behavior of the OptaPlanner?

Extracts of the relevant classes are pasted below.

**Exam Class:**

```java
@PlanningEntity()
public class Exam {
    ...
    
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "roomRange")
    private Room room;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "timeGrainRange")
    private List<TimeGrain> availableTimeGrains;
```

**Filter Class:**

```java
public class PartiallyLockedExamChangeMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<ExamTimetable, ChangeMove<ExamTimetable>> {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<ExamTimetable> scoreDirector, ChangeMove<ExamTimetable> selection) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Solver Config:**

```xml
<solver ...>
    <constructionHeuristic>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <filterClass>ch.package.PartiallyLockedExamChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </constructionHeuristic>
    ...
</solver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Semi-pinned (semi-immovable) planning entities isn't support out-of-the-box yet. [Vote for this issue.](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-124)

**Workaround**

- Ether don't filter it and just add a hard constraint to keep one variable fixed. This isn't 100% efficient, but it works.
- Tailor all the moves for both the ConstructionHeuristic and LocalSearch: ChangeMoves of timeslot aren't filtered, but changeMoves of room are filtered on pinned room entities. Filter on the entity selector for changeMoves, not the move selector. For SwapMoves it's even more complex because they swap both the timeslot and the room. This approach is a lot of work, a maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We put the feature on hold until OptaPlanner adds support for it. Thanks for your reply and possible workarounds.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as @RaphaelJenni but don't have much experience with Optaplanner. Where can I find an example for adding a hard constraint for fixing the room?